# Using a pre-populated map in Android with Google Maps SDK

Tags: android, performance, android-maps-v2

I am currently attempting to implement a map in my app with pre-populated markers. The user clicks a button and it opens the map Activity. My question is, is there a performance friendly way of populating the map with those markers. The markers do not contain a lot of data, only a title and a description. I am thinking in the lines of loading the map behind the scenes whilst the application loads, or chunking the loading depending on where the user has currently set the map to look at. Any advice is very welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As I can see, many big developers just put all markers at once. Just try and check performance, All based on number of those

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load the map in a fragment that is not visible to the user while the user does not click on the button you indicate, and you load the markers using an asynchronous thread. Perhaps the case will arise that the user makes the process so fast that the markers are not loaded, but the map will be.

The use of Fragments would be best for this scenario, you can view the I/O conference to make the work of the Fragments clearer to you asynchronously:

Android Jetpack: how to smartly use Fragments in your UI (Google I/O '18): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WVPH48lUzGY&frags=pl%2Cwn